# Writing a comment when a post is published in the telegram channel

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

The following error occurs when publishing a post `'Message' object has no attribute 'NewMessage'`. (line 19)

I can't figure out what the reason is. Here's all the code (I removed the api data on purpose):

```
import random

from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import telethon.errors

api_id = 0000000  
api_hash = 'testtest3333'
client = TelegramClient('cheat_sand', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

messages = ['Hello', 'Bye']

chat_id = -1000000000 


@client.on(events.NewMessage(chat_id))
async def main(event):
    try:
        await client.send_message(message=random.choice(messages), entity=-1000000000, comment_to=event.NewMessage) 
    except telethon.errors.RPCError:
        pass


client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Very long I can not solve this problem, I tried different accounts, channels, but still this problem.
Would be very grateful for help.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by `comment_to=event.NewMessage`.

If you want to reply on a message, you should use `reply_to` and not `comment_to` like so:
`reply_to=event.message.id`

---

Demo code to reply to each message:

```py
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

client = TelegramClient(?????)
client.start()

@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def main(event):
    await client.send_message(event.message.from_id, message='Something', reply_to=event.message.id)

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: This will work, but note that it can be simplified to `await event.reply('Something')`.